# How to automatically load default pictures when creating a new user in django

Tags: python, django

Whenever I create a new user and try to log-in that user my default picture wasn't loading and there's no error on my console, but when I click my view profile(profile.html) that's when my default picture will show up on my sidebar. https://ibb.co/bR79XpJ this is the url of my screenshot.

```py
models.py
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete =models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')
    update = models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Profile,self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    img = Image.open(self.image.path)
    if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
        output_size = (300, 300)
        img.thumbnail(output_size)
        img.save(self.image.path)

signals.py
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender = User)
def save_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()

base.html # My sidebar
<img class="rounded-circle account-img" src="{{ user.profile.image.url }}">


profile.html # my view profile
<img class="rounded-circle account-img" src="{{ user.profile.image.url }}">
```

I expect to automatically show my default picture on my sidebar when I create a new user.

Comment: Don't save a default image for every user. It's using up disk space and it's a copy of the same image each time. This doesn't make sense. Just allow `image` to be blank and null, and write a method to return either the `image` if it's there or the default static image url if it's not.

Comment: Note your indentation isn't correct for the code starting at `img = Image.open(...)`, that should be inside the `save()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have `MEDIA_ROOT` set correctly in your `settings.py` and also you have `default.jpg` in your described `MEDIA_ROOT` path. 
If you have set `MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')` then make sure you have `default.jpg` in `BASE_DIR/media/default.jpg`.

Answer (score 0):

To save space, only save the default once in static then include this method in your model class

```
def profile_pic_url (self):
    if self.profile_pic: return self.image.url
    else: return static("path/to/image/default.jpg")
```

You can then access it from templates with `{{ object.profile_pic_url }}`